# Escaping dots in groff

Tags: escaping, manpage, groff

According to `info groff` (section 5.11 Character Translations),
`\.` should print just the dot. However, this is not what seems to happen.
If I render this manpage

```
.TH x x x x
\.SH foo
```

I get `foo` rendered as a section heading, and `.SH` is not printed.

So, why does this happen, and how do I escape the dot (and the apostrophe) at
the begginning of the line in groff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To escape dot at the beginning of line write use `\[char46]` :

```
\[char46]SH foo
```

prints

```
.SH foo
```

This is an expected behavior but should be fixed in manual page. [Here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=682857) is a bug report.

Below you can read the description of both `\\` (shortened)
and `\.`  (from info pages).

```
-- Escape: \\
[...]

`\\' is a `delayed' backslash; more precisely, it is the default
escape character followed by a backslash, which no longer has
special meaning due to the leading escape character. It is _not_
an escape sequence in the usual sense! In any unknown escape
sequence `\X' the escape character is ignored and X is printed.
But if X is equal to the current escape character, no warning is
emitted.

As a consequence, only at top-level or in a diversion a backslash
glyph is printed; in copy-in mode, it expands to a single
backslash which then combines with the following character to an
escape sequence.

[...]

-- Escape: \.
Similar to `\\', the sequence `\.' isn't a real escape sequence.
As before, a warning message is suppressed if the escape character
is followed by a dot, and the dot itself is printed.
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply prepend the dot with a zero-width character:

```
\&.SH foo
```

or switch temporarily to another control character:

```
.cc #
.SH foo
#cc
```